# Can a sentence begin with "But why" or "So why"?

Tags: grammaticality

Can a sentence start with 'But why' or 'So why'?

And what's the meaning and use cases for both of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A sentence may begin with *but* or *so* or any other conjunction. **But** for several generations in the 19th and 20th centuries teachers discouraged this use, because it was often misused or overused. Eventually that hardened into a “rule” *forbidding* the use altogether. It’s really just what I call a *baby rule*, like “Don’t cross the street unless you’re holding somebody’s hand”: a rule you are given until you’re old enough not to need it. Still, a lot of people, especially schoolteachers and examiners, learned this rule when they were young and never outgrew it. **So** I recommend you **not** to use it in tests and graded essays.
2. In questions beginning *But why* or *So why*, the *but* and *so* mean exactly what they mean in any other circumstances. They are conjunctions, and relate what you say next to what you said just before. *But* means “What I say next ***contradicts*** what I have just said (in some way)”, and *so* means “What I say next is ***a consequence of*** what I have just said (in some way)”.

   > Everybody else likes going to the opera. But I don’t.
   >   Everybody else wanted to go to the opera. So I went, too.

   When these conjunctions are used before a question they imply different motivations for the question. *But* typically introduces a request for information; *so* typically introduces a challenge.

   > Everybody likes *La Traviata*, the music is so jolly. **But** why do they like weird stuff like *Wozzeck*?

   The reason why people like the very accessible music of hurdy-gurdy-Verdi doesn’t appear to apply to liking the very challenging music of Alban Berg. I’m confused by this **contradiction**. Please explain.

   > Everybody likes *La Traviata*, the music is so jolly. **So** why do they like weird stuff like *Wozzeck*?

   People like Verdi because his music is accessible. In **consequence**, they should dislike the challenging music of Berg. I demand an explanation of why they in fact **do** like Berg.

Comment: I'm glad someone is brave enough to challenge convention, and let us go into the pool even within 30 minutes of eating. However, I would add that, when proofreading, it's worth taking a second look at these leading conjunctions, and ask yourself if you wouldn't be better off combining them into one sentence; for example: "Everyone else likes going to the opera, but I don't.") One shouldn't feel **obligated** to make such edits, mind you, but one should be wary of overusing the construct, and make improvements when possible.

Comment: @J.R. Quite so. If you have a good reason for breaking the "rule", discard it. If you don't, follow it. **My** good reason here is that I'm illustrating OP's use. In other circumstances I might not do so. It really depends on the scene, the action - and who I hear speaking the line.